# AutoMapper -- AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper

I am getting this error:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: Game -> VirtualGame
>
> InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
>
> Property: Timing lambda_method(Closure , object , object ,
>   ResolutionContext )
>
> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

I think I've traced it down to the code block below.  Is there a way to check for null in this block so that this error goes away?

```
cfg.CreateMap<Game, VirtualGame>()

        .ForMember(d => d.GameTiming, opt =>
                {

                    opt.Condition(s => s.GameStartTime != null && s.GameEndTime != null);
                    opt.MapFrom(
                        s => new Timing(s.GameStartTime.Value, s.GameEndTime.Value, s.GameDuration));
                })
```

Oh, and this is what "Timing" is:

```
public Timing(DateTime gameStartTime, DateTime gameEndTime, Int32?
              gameDuration = null)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
opt.PreCondition(s => s.GameStartTime != null && s.GameEndTime != null);
```

[The docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions).

Similarly, there is a precondition. The difference is that it runs sooner in the mapping process, before the source value is resolved (think MapFrom or ResolveUsing). So the precondition is called, then we decide which will be the source of the mapping (resolving), then the condition is called and finally the destination value is assigned. You can see the steps yourself.

Comment: thanks!  Does that replace my opt.Condition statement I have ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Updated.